# Сгенерировать случайную перестановку на Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

SWI-Prolog.
Пришло в голову такое решение. Получать случайную альтернативу из генерации перестановки в нелексикографическом порядке.

```
position(L,X,[X|L]).
position([H|T1],X,[H|T2]):-position(T1,X,T2).

transposition([],[]).
transposition([H|T],L):- transposition(T,T1),
position(T1,H,L).

% fixed permutation
permutation(In, Out) :- len(In, Length), fact(Length, Count), permutation(In, Out, Count), !.
permutation(_, _, 0):-!.
permutation(In, Out, Count) :- Count > 0, transposition(In, Out), rand(Stop, 0, 10), write(Count), nl,  Stop < 5, Count1 is Count - 1, permutation(In, Out, Count1); Stop >=5,!.
```

Как заставить данную программу остановиться, когда Stop >= 5 к примеру.

Comment: или может быть есть какой-то встроенный предикат получения случайной альтернативы, знаю что есть для получения всех альтернатив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [предикатом](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=random_permutation/2) `random_permutation` из библиотеки `random`.

```
3 ?- use_module(library(random)).
%  library(pairs) compiled into pairs 0.00 sec, 4,568 bytes
% library(random) compiled into random 0.03 sec, 46,624 bytes
true.

4 ?- L=[1,2,3,4,5], random_permutation(L,K).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
K = [1, 3, 2, 4, 5].
```

Comment: использовать буду готовое решение, но
можете ещё подсказать, в чём конкретно был косяк с Stop >=5, почему он продолжал дальше доказывать при бэктрекинге.
пробовал переписывать, но всё равно не получается
permutation(_, _, 0, _):-!.
permutation(_, _, _, Rand) :- Rand > 5, !.
permutation(In, Out, Count, Rand) :- transposition(In, Out),  write(Count), nl, Count1 is Count - 1, rand(Rand, 0, 10), permutation(In, Out, Count1, Rand),!.

Comment: Одна из проблем была с расстановкой скобок, каждая альтернатива должна быть в скобках. Более того, лучше было воспользоваться if then else: A -> B ; C